# mysql querying 2 columns that refer to 1 column in different table

Tags: mysql, join

Sorry if question has been asked but I was not able to relate any answers I found to my situation.

I have created a temp table for this problem:

```
describe temp;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id        | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| artist    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| title     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| id_genre  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| id_genre2 | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The other relevent table is a list of genres.

I want to create a query that results in a combination of these 2 queries.

```
select temp.title,genre.name
from temp
join genre on genre.id = temp.id_genre;

+------------------------+--------------+
| title                  | genre1       |
+------------------------+--------------+
| Tight Capris - 1958-B  | Rockabilly   |
| Endless Sleep - 1958-5 | MyFavourites |
| Daisy Mae - 1966       | Rockabilly   |
| Fire of love - 1966-58 | Rockabilly   |
| Stormy - 1963          | Pop          |
+------------------------+--------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

select temp.title,genre.name as genre2
from temp
join genre on genre.id = temp.id_genre2;

+------------------------+------------+
| title                  | genre2     |
+------------------------+------------+
| Tight Capris - 1958-B  | Rockabilly |
| Endless Sleep - 1958-5 | Rockabilly |
| Daisy Mae - 1966       | Rockabilly |
| Fire of love - 1966-58 | Rockabilly |
| Stormy - 1963          | Pop        |
+------------------------+------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Notice the genre difference in the 1 title: Endless Sleep

I would like to create a result that looks like this except to replace the genre.id with the name of the genre:

```
+------------------------+----------+-----------+
| title                  | id_genre | id_genre2 |
+------------------------+----------+-----------+
| Tight Capris - 1958-B  |      163 |       163 |
| Endless Sleep - 1958-5 |      161 |       163 |
| Daisy Mae - 1966       |      163 |       163 |
| Fire of love - 1966-58 |      163 |       163 |
| Stormy - 1963          |       99 |        99 |
+------------------------+----------+-----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join table `Genre` twice because there are two columns on table `temp` that is dependent on it.

```
SELECT  temp.title,
        a.name GenreA,
        b.Name GenreB
FROM    temp
        INNER JOIN genre a 
            ON a.id = temp.id_genre
        INNER JOIN genre b 
            ON b.id = temp.id_genre2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2bec7/2)

OUTPUT

```
╔════════════════════════╦══════════════╦════════════╗
║         TITLE          ║    GENREA    ║   GENREB   ║
╠════════════════════════╬══════════════╬════════════╣
║ Tight Capris - 1958-B  ║ Rockabilly   ║ Rockabilly ║
║ Endless Sleep - 1958-5 ║ MyFavourites ║ Rockabilly ║
║ Daisy Mae - 1966       ║ Rockabilly   ║ Rockabilly ║
║ Fire of love - 1966-58 ║ Rockabilly   ║ Rockabilly ║
║ Stormy - 1963          ║ Pop          ║ Pop        ║
╚════════════════════════╩══════════════╩════════════╝
```

Comment: Thanks! It works great. I guess I have a lot of studying to do because I don't fully understand the syntax of the query.

Comment: How could I filter that further with particular genres. For example where genre1 = 'rockabilly' (which doesn't work)

Comment: you should not be using the `ALIAS` but instead the original column name, see here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2bec7/3

Comment: actually `AS` keyword is optional.

Answer (score 1):

So this is what you need?

```
SELECT
    title,
    genre1.name as genre1,
    genre2.name as genre2
FROM 
    temp
INNER JOIN genre as genre1
    ON genre1.id = id_genre
INNER JOIN genre as genre2
    ON genre2.id = id_genre2
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the great speedy response. Also Stephan, I'm more familiar with the syntax you used so that helps me understand the others better.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Stephan that you need to JOIN *genre* table twice.
But it might be a good idea to use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT  temp.title,
        a.name GenreA,
        b.Name GenreB
FROM    temp
        LEFT OUTER JOIN genre a 
            ON a.id = temp.id_genre
        LEFT OUTER JOIN genre b 
            ON b.id = temp.id_genre2
```

This will help if you have records in temp that have NULL in one of the id_genre columns, or have an id that doesn't match a row in genre table.

Added:

In reference to "How could I filter that further with particular genres. For example where genre1 = 'rockabilly' (which doesn't work).":

At the and add

```
HAVING genre1 = 'rockabilly'
```

Comment: How could I filter that further with particular genres. For example where genre1 = 'rockabilly' (which doesn't work).

Comment: Pete, I have added additional information for the filter you requested. If my answer is helpful, please upvote or accept it. If not, please comment below, and I will revise and improve my answer.